# Button Positioning with Image Sizes Changes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am playing with Xamarin Forms and I would like to add a `Button` programmatically. Nothing easier, but I've noted that the results vary greatly if the button has an `Image` rather than a `Text`.

Now I have this XAML that defines a three-layered screen (header, content, footer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing" 
             x:Class="Testing.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <!-- Content -->
        <StackLayout x:Name="contentpage" Padding="10,100,10,100">

            <!-- Header -->
            <StackLayout x:Name="header" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Button Text="ABCD" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>        
                <Button Text="EFGH" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>        
            </StackLayout>
            <!-- /Header -->


            <!-- Center -->    
            <StackLayout x:Name="content" Opacity="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" >
                <Button x:Name="test" Text="Fire fire fire" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" />
            </StackLayout>
            <!-- /Center -->


            <!-- Bottom -->    
            <StackLayout x:Name="buttons" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Button Text="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                <Button Text="2" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                <Button Text="3" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                <Button Text="4" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                <Button Text="5" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
            </StackLayout>
            <!-- /Bottom -->

        </StackLayout> <!-- Content -->

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

And in the corresponding C# source I add a button to the `content`:

```
var custombutton = new Button();
custombutton.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
custombutton.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
custombutton.Image = "mountain.jpg";
//custombutton.Text = "hello";


content.Children.Add(
    custombutton
);
```

As you can see, I want to change the button's properties by setting an image, but the layout changes dramatically.

[image: results]

As you can see, if I add the button with a text everything's ok (left), but as I change the button's image, the button seems to not obey its vertical options (right), or it adds some weird padding. Of course I would like just to add buttons with texts or images without losing the footer `StackLayout`, but I don't know what's happening here.

Am I missing something here?

## Sizes Update

As suggested, I've tried different layouts, however, I ended up with the same results. This last test is with a `Grid`, and inside a `ScrollView` with a `StackLayout`. Different views and arrangements won't change anything in my project.

What matters is **the image size** as you can see:

[image: size-tests]

Image sizes here are `1668 × 796` and `355 × 190` pixels.

A **fully functional source is here available for download**: [link to the solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ol2bkhe2pmdgeu0/Testing.zip?dl=0).

## Controls Update

Using an `Image` works flawlessly, regardless of the image size. No clue on why a `Button` adds such a huge space dependent on the image.

Comment: It is not a website, stop thinking about it in those terms. You are dealing with relative sizes on vastly differing screen orientations and dimensions. You could use an absolute layout, get the screen dimensions and place the button in the center but you will find this approach to be maintainable. My suggestion would be to default to using grids, determine what you want at the top or bottom of a screen and place the middle stuff in the 'rest' of the available space. It also appears since there is  a 'fire fire fire' control at the top on the code behind that the code behind is not a full ex

Comment: @ClintLandry "stop thinking about it in those terms" is exactly what I do, since I don't do any web-related programming (80% C++, rest is Python and Lua). I will go with the grids as suggested. My question remains: what is really happening here with the image?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, [result looks good to me](https://imgur.com/a/R79Cssn). Did you share your whole code in the question? Are there any custom renderers in play which may cause the layout changes? Does the layout also change if you choose a smaller image, like in my screenshot?

Comment: @DennisSchröer I've added a link to my solution and updated the question. It seems that image sizes really matter a lot, and the actual layout I use to create buttons won't change the results a bit.

Comment: I think a dirty solution might be to set button's `height` property to a fixed value, but that's just an idea.

Comment: @DennisSchröer you're right but that would be a very ugly hack. Note also that `Image` instead of a button doesn't suffer from this weirdness.

Comment: You could add `Image` with a `GestureRecognizer` instead of a `Button` then. Not an answer to your question, but it would be a solution to your problem

Comment: @DennisSchröer yes, right now my code is using a gesture recognizer, but it's kinda puzzling to me why a button behaves that differently.